# Executing extension before SpringExtension

Tags: spring, docker, integration-testing, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I'm trying to implement integration testing in my app and have test class like that:

```
@ExtendWith(value={MyDockerExtension.class})
@ExtendWith(value={SpringExtension.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={...})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.LifeCycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestClass{ ... }
```

Is there any way to make MyDockerExtension execute some code, before whole SpringExtension start working and generate whole Context with Configurationc classes?

I've heard that order in which we declare extensions is the key, but sadly MyDockerExtension that implements `BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback` executes right before test method and after whole context is loaded. In that situation it's to late to start containers with docker, becuase since whole context is loaded my app already tried to connect to the container.

Answer (score 4):

At first I was skeptical about the order being fixed but [you're correct](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative):

> Extensions registered declaratively via `@ExtendWith` will be executed in the order in which they are declared in the source code.

Regarding the `MyDockerExtension`, you may want to look at the extension point [`TestInstancePostProcessor`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstancePostProcessor.html), which is called before `@BeforeAll`. [`SpringExtension` implements it](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.html) and I guess it's there where it sets up the application context. If you also implement it, you should be able to act before it does.

Comment: As the author of the `SpringExtension`, I can confirm that @Nicolai is correct. The `ApplicationContext` is loaded first (typically) when performing dependency injection which is triggered via the `TestInstancePostProcessor` extension API. Since you're using `PER_CLASS` test instance lifecycle semantics, the `BeforeAllCallback` extension API is invoked _after_ the `TestInstancePostProcessor`. If you were using `PER_METHOD` lifecycle, it would be the other way around.